# Filter between two rows TITLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like that

```
ProductCode | ProductName | Quantity
-------------------------------------
TITLEA      |     null    |    null
  A1        |     A2      |    A3
  B1        |     B2      |    B3
  C1        |     C2      |    C3
TITLEB      |     null    |    null
  D1        |     D2      |    D3
  E1        |     E3      |    E3
  F1        |     F2      |    F3
TITLEC      |     null    |    null
  G1        |     G2      |    G3
```

Is it possible to filter between two rows TITLE, like between TITLEA and TITLEB. When choosing between the two row titles, it will filter the data row between them:

```
  A1        |     A2      |    A3
  B1        |     B2      |    B3
  C1        |     C2      |    C3
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as rows being between other rows, unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is NO, unless it sharing a same key for the data you want to filter like groupid = 1;